# UDP client can not recieve data from server in C++

Tags: c++, udp

I am new for C++. I tried to write a UDP client and server in C++. The server can receive data from client. But the client can not receive data from server. No matter what data the server sends, the method `recvfrom` in client always returns 0.

The client code is below:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
 
int main()
{
    SOCKET sock_Client; 
    WSADATA WSAData;
    char receBuf[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
    char sendBuf[BUFFER_SIZE]; 

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WSAData) != 0)
    {
        printf("initialation fails!");
        return -1;
    }

    sock_Client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    SOCKADDR_IN addr_server; 
    addr_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_server.sin_port = htons(4567);
    addr_server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    SOCKADDR_IN sock;
    int len = sizeof(sock);
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "input data to send:";
        cin >> sendBuf;
        sendto(sock_Client, sendBuf, strlen(sendBuf), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&addr_server, sizeof(SOCKADDR));
        //int last=recv(sock_Client, receBuf, strlen(receBuf), 0); // 
        int last = recvfrom(sock_Client, receBuf, strlen(receBuf), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&sock, &len);
        if (last > 0)
        {
            receBuf[last] = '\0'; 
            if (strcmp(receBuf, "bye") == 0)
            {
                cout << "server stops talking..." << endl;
                closesocket(sock_Client);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("received data：%s\n", receBuf);
            }
        }
    }
    closesocket(sock_Client);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

The server code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    char receBuf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char Response[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WSAData) != 0)
    {
        printf("initialation fails!");
        exit(1);
    }
    SOCKET sockServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sockServer == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Failed socket() \n");
        return 0;
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr_Server; 
    addr_Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_Server.sin_port = htons(4567);
    addr_Server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(sockServer, (SOCKADDR*)&addr_Server, sizeof(addr_Server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {        
        printf("Failed socket() %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr_Clt;

    int fromlen = sizeof(SOCKADDR);
    while (true)
    {
        int last = recvfrom(sockServer, receBuf, 1024, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&addr_Clt, &fromlen);
        if (last > 0)
        {            
            receBuf[last] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(receBuf, "bye") == 0)
            {
                cout << " client stop talking..." << endl;
                closesocket(sockServer);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("received data（%s）：%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr_Clt.sin_addr), receBuf);
            }
        }
        cout << "anser client:";//<br>Response = “”；
        cin >> Response; 
        sendto(sockServer, Response, strlen(Response), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&addr_Clt, sizeof(SOCKADDR));
    }

    closesocket(sockServer);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone know what is wrong with the code?

The code runs in Windows. So, `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` has to be added into `CMakeLists.txt`. If you want to run the code, please notice that.

Comment: `strlen(receBuf)` is wrong. it should be `sizeof receBuf`: `strlen` is to compute the size of a zero terminated string, but you just have a buffer

Comment: @ Mathieu It works. Thanks very much.